# How to handle Android ListView's item click for button and a specific area ?

Tags: android, listview, button, onclick

I tried to create a row for customized listView in android, so I put button, imagebutton, and textview. But it didn't work. Does anybody know how can I handle this case? I want it to be something like the following image:

[image]

Comment: Check this link : [How to handle Button click and Listview click on a single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726709/how-to-handle-button-click-and-listview-click-on-a-single-row)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `onTouch` listener to your video Image and items of list.So, when you touch on any list item or video image, it will play regarding actions.

Also for arrow  you can implement `onTouch`. Also you can implement quickAction widget for your arrow options. Check out the quickAction [here](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/quick-actions)

The QuickAction Tutorial is [here](http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/63)

Answer (score 0):

You should set custom adapter for your ListView and override the `getView()` method, so that you could handle the `onClick` listeners for each widget in your ListView item.

Look here for more info: [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)